# Magento 2: Why Does My Custom Controller Generate an Interceptor?

Tags: configuration, controllers, magento2, routing, interceptor

I recently created a basic routing configuration for a test module

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="helloworld" frontName="helloworld">
            <module name="Pulsestorm_Helloworld" />
        </route>
    </router>    
</config>
```

and then created a controller file at

```
app/code/Pulsestorm/Helloworld/Controller/Index/Index.php
```

Everything work as expected -- but I was surprised to discover that Magento had automatically created an interceptor for my new controller.

```
var/generation/Pulsestorm/Helloworld/Controller/Index/Index/Interceptor.php
```

I didn't configure any plugins for my controller -- so I'm little confused as to why Magento generated an interceptor.

What makes Magento 2 automatically create an Interceptor for new controllers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Plugins are defined on interface. So if you define plugin for concrete interface

```
<type name="Magento\Framework\App\ActionInterface">
    <plugin name="log" type="Magento\Logging\App\Action\Plugin\Log" sortOrder="95"/>
</type>
```

then plugin will be work on all classes that implements it and IT will generate interceptor proxies for them. That's why Magento 2 will automatically create a interceptor for your controller (that implements Magento\Framework\App\ActionInterface).

Comment: thank you!  Quick question -- where are you seeing the `<type/>` definition for `Magento\Framework\App\ActionInterface` -- no such thing shows up in my installation (or, at least, I couldn't find it with grep/ack)

Comment: Sorry for late answer. In Magento/Backend/etc/adminhtml/di.xml we have
     <type name="Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action">
        <plugin name="storeCheck" disabled="true" />
    </type>